# Confusion about a separation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm confused about the following separation theorem.

Given two nonempty, convex subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$. There is a hyperplane that properly (sic) separates $A$ and $B$ if and only if their relative interiors are disjoint.

Proper separation means that neither set is fully contained in the separating hyperplane.

My question is simple: What about any rectangle and one of its sides?
They are clearly nonempty and convex. Their relative interiors are the inside of the rectangle and the inner line segment of the side which are clearly disjoint. But the only separating hyperplane will fully contain the side and thus not separate properly.

Is my reasoning flawed or is there some assumption missing in the statement?

Comment: I think what is flawed is your interpretation of the [definition of proper separation](https://www.akshayagrawal.com/files/separation-theorems.pdf): one of the two sets may be contained in the separating hyperplane.

Comment: @AnneBauval You are right. The Definition of proper separation in the script that you linked is that "at least one set is not contained in the separating hyperplane".

Comment: Oh, indeed the given definition for proper separation states that "both sets are not fully contained in [the hyperplane]" and apparently means what you say. Thanks for clearing that up. If you wish to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.